# How to split column name separately in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe

I have one csv file in which a lot of columns are there.
After reading the csv file while printing the columns, its printing the col name as a full string not separate col name.

I need separate column name. Can you please help me how to do this?

code:

```
df1 = pd.read_csv("D:/Users/SPate233/Downloads/iMedical/AMPIL_DEV/MDM_PRODUCT_VIEW/MDM_PRODUCT_VIEW_H.csv", sep = '|')
print(list(df1.columns))
print(df1['SERIES_ID'][2])
```

Output:

```
['RECORD_ID,MDM_ID,SERIES_ID,RELTIO_ID,COUNTRY_ID,PRODUCT_NAME,GROUP_TYPE,JANSSEN_MSTR_PRDCT_NM']
KeyError: SERIES_ID
```

Desired Output:

```
['RECORD_ID','MDM_ID','SERIES_ID','RELTIO_ID','COUNTRY_ID','PRODUCT_NAME','GROUP_TYPE','JANSSEN_MSTR_PRDCT_NM']
```

Comment: Try changing the separator to `sep = ','`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you entered the wrong separator, so it's reading the entire first line as a single column. try:

```
df1 = pd.read_csv("D:/Users/SPate233/Downloads/iMedical/AMPIL_DEV/MDM_PRODUCT_VIEW/MDM_PRODUCT_VIEW_H.csv", sep = ',')
```